# Problem in inserting commas in the numbers using regex : Python

Tags: python, regex

I am learning `lookahead` and `lookbehind` in regex and trying to apply commas to a number between every 3 digits. I am stuck here:

```
text = "The population of India is 1300598526 and growing."
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(?<=\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+\b)')
line = re.sub(pattern, r',', text)
print(line)
```

expected output:

```
"The population of India is 1,300,598,526 and growing"
```

actual output `None`. The pattern doesn't match. I have tried fiddling with the pattern and found out that the leading `\b` is the culprit. The pattern works fine without this. Why is that so? Please clarify.

I'd prefer to know of the error in the abovementioned pattern instead of a newly crafted pattern to achieve the same thing. Thanks.

Comment: At a word boundary, if you lookbehind for a digit, then the following character must not be a digit, else it wouldn't be a word boundary.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I didn't get your point. Could you please be more specific using the above-mentioned example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex starts with `\b(?<=\d)` and uses a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). That position will only match at the end of `1300598526`. The word boundary does not match between the digits so the part that follows `(?=(\d\d\d)+\b)` can not match.

One way to solve this converting digits not inside a word could be to split on a space to get the words. Then map each item and check if the consists of 4 or more digits `\A\d{4,}\Z` and add the comma after 3 digits using:

```
\d(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))
```

**Explanation**

- `\d` Match a digit
- `(?=` positive lookahead to assert what is on the right is

  - `(?:\d{3})+` repeat sets of 3 digits
  - `(?!\d)`Negative lookahead to assert what is on the right is not a digit
- `)` Close positive lookahead

For example:

```
import re

text = "The population 12test1234 of India is 1300598526 and growing."
pattern = re.compile(r"\d(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))")
subst = r"\g<0>,"

res = map(lambda x: re.sub(pattern, subst, x) if re.match(r"\A\d{4,}\Z", x) else x, text.split(' '))
print (" ".join(res))
```

Result

```
The population 12test1234 of India is 1,300,598,526 and growing.
```

See the [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yrrxh9/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/rSw7Az)